# how to select a class which is children of many elements

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="rightsidebox">
    <div class="item-info-list">
        <p>Model: AIDCU</p>
        <div class="product-details">
            <p></p>
            <div class="price-box"> <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-1617-related">
      <span class="price">$8.99</span></span>
            </div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to make a style for price and make the color green just in a case it is in the rightbox div and I want to use css , I cannot change the structure because it is a theme and it should not have conflict with other prices in other themes

I can use `div.rightsidebox>div.item-info-list`

but I cannot go further because of the paragraph in there 
how can I solve it? I have weakness in using ">" and multiple classes in each other

Comment: .rightsidebox .price { color: green; }

EDIT: **Usage of > - operator**

The element>element selector is used to select elements with a specific parent.

Note: Elements that are not directly a child of the specified parent, are not selected. [More info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)

Comment: It should, try to use !important. ... .price { color: green !important; }

Comment: @Doodlebunch it worked for me please submit your answer so I can choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.rightsidebox .price { color: green !important; } // important to override other styles
```

EDIT: **Usage of > - selectorr**

The element>element selector is used to select elements with a specific parent. Note: Elements that are not directly a child of the specified parent, are not selected. [More info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)

Comment: Thank you for being exact n quick:)

Answer (score 2):

This I believe is what you are looking for:

```
div.rightsidebox>div.item-info-list>div.product-details {
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RF5e7/

Comment: it is color:#ff0000; and yes it is working in jsfiddle but not working for me seems it has conflict somewhere

Answer (score 1):

If you merely just want to select the `price` and make it green if it is contained by rightbox:

```
.rightsidebox .price {
     color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: yeah it worked thank you to you and doodle I don't know which one of you answered me first

Comment: doodle answered one min sooner in comments so btw thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

```
div.rightsidebox>div.item-info-list .price{
    color: green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5C3d/) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
.rightsidebox .item-info-list p {
  /* code */
}
```

This would go down to the paragraph element inside the classes defined there inside the stylesheet (above off course).

You don't need to be using `div.rightsidebox` that is required **only** if you're having class names for multiple elements. Otherwise only `.rightsidebox` is OK.

You can learn more about the CSS child selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors